# Locale always get reset after onCreate

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, locale

I try to setting locale in app, first run it works. But, after onCreate() (Rotate) will get reset to default language and I can't change language in app after reset.

I use SharePreference to save locale value

PrefUtils.java to get value from SharePreference

```
public class PrefUtil {
    private static final String PREF_SETTINGS_LANGUAGE = "pref_settings_language";
    public static String getLocale(Context context){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        String loadLanguage = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_SETTINGS_LANGUAGE, "");
        Log.d("LoadLanguage", loadLanguage);
        return loadLanguage;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java to set locale, I put in onCreate and onResume

```
private void appLocale(String localeCode){
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Comment: I think you must try other life-cycle component rather an onCreate. Like onResume based on your condition when to localize the application.

Comment: create a baseActivity and set Local there

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh yes, i save locale code in SharePreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In activity class, you should override `attachBaseContext(base : Context)`.

Create an abstract class `BaseActivity` and extends it on `MainActivity`.

By doing this you don't have to write `onAttachBaseContext()` in every activity class but should extend `BaseActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`.

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base))
    }
}
```

To retain language setting you should also override `attachBaseContext(base:Context)` in Application class.

```
class App : Application() {

   override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, LocaleHelper.LANG_EN))
    }
}
```

If you need a helper class of localization, here is the one. The code is in Kotlin, but I think you will understand.

```
object LocaleHelper {

    private const val SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language"

    const val LANG_EN = "en"
    const val LANG_ES = "es"

    val languageMap = hashMapOf(
        LANG_EN to "English",
        LANG_ES to "Spanish"
    )

    fun onAttach(context: Context): Context {
        val lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().language)
        return setLocale(context, lang)
    }

    fun onAttach(context: Context, defaultLanguage: String): Context {
        val lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage)
        return setLocale(context, lang)
    }

    fun getLanguage(context: Context): String? {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().language)
    }

    fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String?): Context {
        persist(context, language)
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            updateResources(context, language)
        } else {
            updateResourcesLegacy(context, language)
        }

    }

    private fun getPersistedData(context: Context, defaultLanguage: String): String? {
        val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage)
    }

    private fun persist(context: Context, language: String?) {
        val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        val editor = preferences.edit()

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language)
        editor.apply()
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String?): Context {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val configuration = context.resources.configuration
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }

    // used for api level < 24
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String?): Context {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val resources = context.resources
        val configuration = resources.configuration
        configuration.locale = locale
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
        return context
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand kotlin code. But, i think your code like (https://androidwave.com/android-multi-language-support-best-practices/)

it works. But, i must rotate (onCreate) to change language. i put PrefUtil.setLocale() in onResume

Note : onResume() not work to change language